# Angular material: table inside mat-expansion not aligned to other table

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, angular7

Im added to Angular website  for table ,that table col is not align ,any one know how to do that correctly ?
Thanks

```
<div class="table-responsive ">
            <table class="table" style="width: 100%">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="50">ID</th>
                <th scope="col" width="300">Book Name</th>
                <th scope="col" width="250">Total Book</th>
                <th scope="col" width="250">Date</th>
                <th scope="col" width="250">Remarks</th>
                <th scope="col" width="250">Booking Date</th>
                <th scope="col" width="250">Booking Status</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>

          <mat-accordion>
            <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true; openContent(order)"
                                 (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
              <mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="customCollapsedHeight"
                                          [expandedHeight]="customExpandedHeight">
                <table class="table ">
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="50">12</td>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="300">ABC</td>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="250">100}</td>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="250">10-11-2018</td>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="250">Jhone Doe</td>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="250">10-05-2019</td>
                    <td class="tb-td-txt" width="250">Completed</td>
                         </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          </mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things...

- the lower table is a child of `.mat-expansion-panel`, so for the table outside it, we mimic the `padding:0 24px`
- but there is also a down arrow for `mat-expansion-indicator` so we gotta increase the padding on the right side by 8px
- next, we text-align center for the bottom table (which is inside the mat-expansion) so that the effect is similar
- I have also put a red borders on the `<td>` so that you can see this

relevant **CSS**:

```
th, td{border:1px solid red;}
.table-responsive>.table{padding:0 32px 0 24px;}
mat-expansion-panel-header .table td{text-align: center}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8ufzg)